# Asymptotic analysis - if f(n) = Ω(g(n)), how to prove ln(f(n)) = Ω(ln(g(n)))?

Tags: asymptotics, logarithms

Is the following statement true, if so, how can I prove it?

```
if f(n) = Ω(g(n)), is also true that ln(f(n)) = Ω(ln(g(n)))?
```

Since `f(n) >= c*g(n)`, I divided the problem into two branches:

If `f(n) = g(n)`, it's also true that `ln(x) = ln(x)` and the statement it's true.

If `f(n) > g(n)`, then the value for `ln` is greater, if the argument is greater:

```
x > y; ln(x) > ln(y)
```

Is there something wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Hi, Ondrej, welcome to Math.SE! Thanks for your question. Hope you stay and contribute both questions and answers to the site :).

Comment: Since $\ln(\cdot)$ is an increasing function, certainly $f = \Omega(g)$ if and only if $\ln f = \Omega (\ln g)$. But you need one more level -- or is it a typo and you meant to ask if $\ln f = \Omega(\ln g)$ instead?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that was a typo.

Comment: But what's bugging me is the c in the definition of Ω. The "=" branch might not be true because of that.

Comment: I'll write it up as a formal answer, it's not a problem.

Comment: @gt6989b Sorry but "if and only if" is quite wrong here.

Comment: @Did sorry, you are right, it only holds one way...

Comment: I think there needs to be some condition on the domain, e.g. the $\Omega$ estimate holds as $n \to \infty$.  Otherwise take $f(n) = n$ and $g(n) = 2n$.  Then $f(n) \geq \frac{1}{2}\,g(n)$ on $n \geq 1$ but $\log f(n) \not\geq c \log g(n)$ on $n \geq 1$ for any $c > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false in general without some further conditions.

For example take $f(n) = n$ and $g(n) = 2n$.  Then $f(n) \geq \frac{1}{2} g(n)$ on the domain $n \geq 1$ but $\log f(n) \not\geq c \log g(n)$ on the domain $n \geq 1$ for any $c > 0$.  In this case it is only true that $\log f(n) = \Omega(\log g(n))$ as $n \to \infty$.

For another example take $f(n) = \sin(n\pi/6) + 2$ and $g(n) = \sin(n\pi/6) + 3$.  Then $f(n) \geq \frac{1}{2} g(n)$ for all $n$ but $\log f(n) \not\geq c \log g(n)$ for any $c > 0$ on any domain that includes the points $n=9,21,33,45,\ldots$

The statement is true if $g(n) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ and $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ as $n \to \infty$.  For then we can find a $c > 0$ such that

$$
f(n) \geq c\,g(n)
$$

for all $n$ sufficiently large, from which

$$
\log f(n) \geq \log c + \log g(n) \geq \frac{1}{2}\log g(n)
$$

for $n$ large enough.  Thus $\log f(n) = \Omega(\log g(n))$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: The definition of $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ is that there exists a pair of constants $c$ and $n_0$ such that for all $n > n_0$, $f(n) \geq c g(n)$. So $\log n \geq 0.5 \log 2n$ for $n > 2$, means $\log(n) = \Omega(\log 2n)$

Comment: @MichaelBiro that is one definition of $\Omega$.  There is another one that allows the estimate to hold on any set, not just as $n \to \infty$: $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ for $n \in A$ iff there exists a $c>0$ s.t. $|f(n)| \geq c|g(n)|$ for all $n \in A$.

Comment: In asymptotic analysis, I automatically suppose these preconditions - that we're analysing strictly increasing functions (which rules out trigonometric functions) and that we can rely on large enough n. Thanks!

Comment: @OndřejMirtes glad to help.  In that case I'd be happy to expand on my proof in the answer if you think it needs clarification.